# c# how to check if object already exists in a list,if list has multiple items

Tags: c#, list, linq

I am new to Csharp

I have a list that contains multiple elements. Before adding a list object to list, I want to check if that object already exists in list or not.

Below I am giving sample list which has 7 elements in list, but my original requirement has more than 20 elements in a list.

That's why I want to compare list object as is and check if it exists or not.

I tried Contains(), LINQ , FINDALL(). Nothing worked.

I have a very large dataset.

Sample:
This is my list:

```
public class taxDetails
{
    public string record { get; set; }
    public string UpdateCd { get; set; }
    public string EffDt { get; set; }
    public string TermDt { get; set; }
    public string TransCd { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
 }
```

I want to do something like this:

```
taxDetails ti = new taxDetails();

taxDetails.Add(ti);
```

This should be added only if the object "ti" is not already in the list. 
I want it to compare all the 7 elements and determine weather object exists or not.

Comment: Where is the implementation of the `Add` method in `taxDetails` class?

Comment: What you show is not a list, it's a class. A list would look like: `var taxDetailsList = new List<taxDetails>();`

Comment: In the case your code is wrong and you really add it to a list, each `new()` instance is new, so it can't be inside the list.

Comment: 1) Don't say you "tried" something without showing us what you tried. You may have done it wrong. You may have done something that isn't Linq at all, but you thought it was. 2) *"Below I am giving sample list which has 7 elements in list"* You gave no list at all, of any number of elements. Give list, please.

Comment: You could identify (if any) the unique variable or primary key of each record, maybe it is `Id `? If you have that you can simply check if the ID exists before adding, such as `if (!taxDetails.Any(t => t.Id == ti.Id))  taxDetails.Add(ti);`.

Comment: I did create a list in my actual code which is a huge piece of code, for this request, I took a sample piece of it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and it worked.

```
List<Tuple<string>> test = new List<Tuple<string>>()
        {
            new Tuple<string>("dfsg"),
            new Tuple<string>("dfgfd"),
            new Tuple<string>("sdfdsfsdf"),
            new Tuple<string>("123")
        };
        var contians = test.Contains(new Tuple<string>("123"));
```

If I had to guess its because you didnt override the Equals method.

```
public override bool Equals(
object obj )
```

Try implementing that function, for example like the following:

`return this.field1 == obj.field1 && this.field2 == obj.field2 etc`

Comment: I have 15 different List's in my class and each has different set of data elements. In that case how can I override the Equals method ?

Comment: Just like i stated above.

public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return this.field1 == obj.field1 && this.field2 == obj.field2;
}

By default the Equals methods compares pointers for complex types, like objects. Therefor in order to determine if your object is in a list, you need to compare it. In order to compare it, you need to override the equals method.